# Accessing python script return value from bash script

Tags: bash, python

I have a python script (called temp.py) that returns two numbers, formatted as strings and separated by whitespace. For example, the output would look like "23.3 43.6 ". I am trying to print out these values in a bash script. I can print the entire output string via echo $OUTPUT, but I get a bad substitution error when trying to print individual elements. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
OUTPUT=$(python ./scripts/temp.py)
echo $OUTPUT # Prints normally "23.3 43.6 "
echo ${OUTPUT[0]} # error: bad substitution!
```

Comment: Sounds like you are not using bash. Are you maybe calling the script with `sh` instead?

Comment: @terdon: this is bash script.

Comment: @JoonhoPark um. Yes, I know it is a bash script. However, the error the OP describes suggests that this bash script is not being run as a bash script but instead it is being run as an sh script. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems there. First, you are using a shell that doesn't support arrays. Most likely `sh` or `dash`. My guess is that although you have a bash shebang line there, you are calling your script with `sh script.sh` which means it is being interpreted by whatever `sh` is on your system. For example, on `dash` (which is the default `sh` on Debian and Ubuntu), you get:

```
$ out=$(echo 23.3 43.6 )
$ echo ${out[0]}
dash: 2: Bad substitution
```

However, in bash, you would get:

```
$ out=$(echo 23.3 43.6 )
$ echo ${out[0]}
23.3 43.6
```

The next issue is that even if you run this in bash, that isn't how arrays work:

```
$ out=$(echo 23.3 43.6 )
$ echo ${out[0]}
23.3 43.6
$ echo ${out[1]}   ## prints nothing but a newline since the variable is empty

$
```

To get an array in bash, you need to put the elements inside parentheses:

```
$ out=( $(echo 23.3 43.6 ) )
$ echo ${out[0]}
23.3
$ echo ${out[1]}
43.6
```

Comment: It will be run by bash when called by filename directly such as "$script.sh".

Comment: @JoonhoPark yes, of course it will. But, if it were called by `bash` it would not give the error described by the OP. To get what the OP describes, you need to run this with another shell. And what usually happens is that people run it with `sh script.sh` thinking that `sh` is the same as `bash`. Please read the question more closely and you will see the error described.

Comment: your answer is correct and useful to me.